# Open layers - format points to multipolygon

Tags: node.js, openlayers

I'm using two different services, the first one returns a Polygon, like this:

```
0: {type: "Feature", id: "postal_fsa_boundaries.1590", geometry: {type: "Polygon",…},…}

geometry: {type: "Polygon",…}
coordinates: [[[-123.09689608, 49.24042409], [-123.09391444, 49.24036854], [-123.09340615, 49.24035906],…]]
type: "Polygon"
geometry_name: "boundary"
id: "postal_fsa_boundaries.1590"
```

The second service, returns a Points with coordinates, like this:

```
features: [{type: "Feature", id: "active_address.fid-31c7b976_175e990a2fb_664a",…},…]
0: {type: "Feature", id: "active_address.fid-31c7b976_175e990a2fb_664a",…}
geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [-114.0926087, 51.05883014]}
coordinates: [-114.0926087, 51.05883014]
type: "Point"
geometry_name: "the_geom"
id: "active_address.fid-31c7b976_175e990a2fb_664a"
```

at the moment to parse those responses to polygons, I'm using:

```
const multi = new MultiPolygon(fsas.map((f) => f.geometry));
```

where `geomety` type is `Polygon`.

And at the moment to parse it I get:

```
new WKT().writeGeometry(multi)
```

I get a response like:

> ((
> 51.05301895 -114.09479052,51.05305604 -114.09397244,51.05338313 -114.09335017,51.05341011 -114.09167379,51.05706864 -114.0917623,51.0571091 -114.08597946,51.05952998 -114.08607602,51.05956032 -114.09473956,51.05301895 -114.09479052)), ((
> 51.05301895 -114.09479052,51.05305604 -114.09397244,51.05338313 -114.09335017,51.05341011 -114.09167379,51.05706864 -114.0917623,51.0571091 -114.08597946,51.05952998 -114.08607602,51.05956032 -114.09473956,51.05301895 -114.09479052))

That is like I expected.
But I'm not finding the way to do the same with the `Point`.

Does someone have an idea about how to format them properly?
I'm just using `Point([])` but I'm able to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code

```
const addresses = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-114.0926087, 51.05883014]          
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-115.0926087, 52.05883014]          
    }
}]; 

const multi = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon([[addresses.map((f) => f.geometry.coordinates)]]);
console.log(new ol.format.WKT().writeGeometry(multi));
```

produces

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((-114.0926087 51.05883014,-115.0926087 52.05883014)))
```

in the browser. Is that somewhat close?

Comment: yes, it is very close, I just have an error `Could not parse CQL filter list.
Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring Parsing` but I think is because my data

Comment: I think the polygons should be closed, that is, the last vertex should duplicate the first vertex

Comment: I just did it, but now I'm getting: `Invalid number of points in LinearRing (found 3 - must be 0 or &amp;gt;= 4) `

Comment: It means the polygon is not valid. The geometry doesn't make a polygon.

Comment: Right, I removed elements with less than 3 points and now it is working. Thanks!